# Pull to refresh text is not readable in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

In the Stack Exchange Android app, the pull-to-refresh message text color is black which is not readable. It should be either in white color or in some light color.

FYI, it looks readable in this snapshot, but you can try and check it in the app itself.

[image: Screenshot from the Stack Exchange Android app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in version 1.0.26 and higher.

Comment: Yes I can see white colored title text in current version.

Answer (score 1):

While we're at that, maybe the content could also be much whiter, instead of gray, so that it's visible while looking at the app under sunlight. I have anti-glare screen protector, but it's still hard to read.